# Small but powerful speakers

Tags: audio, amplifier, speakers, class-d

Why are powerful speakers like above 20w or 80w not small? I have never seen enough in the market which are under 3 inch but of 80W.  The opposite is also true, some big speakers are of low wattage. Compare [5 inch 10W](http://www.mcmelectronics.com/product/55-4604) and [5 inch 100W](http://www.parts-express.com/galaxy-audio-s5n-8-5-neodymium-full-range-driver-8-ohm--290-020) (same dimension but different power).

So clearly its not only about the dimensions. To move more air does not mean to have a bigger speaker? Something else is also in play. What is it?

So for my analog [20W stereo amp](http://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-20w-stereo-audio-amplifier-class-d-max9744/downloads), what is the smallest possible full range speaker I can get? Aiming to make it small like beats pill, is it possible with this analog power or do I have to shift to digital processing?

And as a side-note, if separating freq with crossovers is suggested, how would I do it? For each channel a tweeter and subwoofer?

And how do companies, like Libratone and Bose, create small speakers with high power([70W, 100W](http://www.libratone.com/wp-content/uploads/download/Libratone_family.pdf)), though they do separate it with crossovers? So is this the way to make it really small and portable? Or is it because of using DSP chips instead of analog?

Comment: Why is a 1 watt resistor bigger than a 0.5 watt resistor?

Answer (score 5):

Standard speaker maximum power is limited by coil resistance (more resistance - more heat) and mechanical durability.

High power at small size can be archieved by removing low frequencies from signal and heat  from coil resistance is power limiting factor.

At high frequency - membrane moves faster than at low frequency, so it needs more acceleration (and more power can be used at speaker same size).

For low frequencies - mechanical durability matters a lot. You also need bigger surface to use that much power for just pushing air (and move membrane mass).

> To move more air does not mean to have a bigger speaker? Something
>   else is also in play. What is it?

**First thing** to consider is amount/volume of air moved by speaker membrane (Vd speaker parameter) This is related with membrane surface area (Sd speaker parameter) and maximum membrane travel (Xmax speaker parameter).

Small speaker needs higher membrane travel to push same volume of air. It's easier to build a speaker with low travel and high surface, than small surface and long travel. Thats why low cost speakers are bigger than more expensive speakers.

**Second thing** is frequency range of speaker and resonance effects. This is more complicated.

> So for my analog 20W stereo amp, what is the smallest possible full
>   range speaker I can get?

There is no answer for that question. It depends on what you mean by "full range" and what you mean by "size" (is it speaker diameter or box size). You can look what is available on the market (computer speakers with similar power, mini stereo systems etc). That should give you idea what is possible and what is not.

> And how do companies, like Libratone and Bose, create small speakers
>   with high power(70W, 100W), though they do separate it with
>   crossovers?

Small, very high power speakers have narrow frequency range. You can buy 100W 3000-20000Hz speaker with 100W power and 1 inch membrane or speaker that has 300-3000Hz frequency range, 80W and 4 inch diameter but this is not full range.